# define Header in Ajax for generating zip PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fpdf, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to generate zip file with ZipArchive Class, containing pdf file generated too with FPDF library.

I'm using ajax and PHP to do that, the problem is that I don't know how to set Headers in ajax to force the download in the browser.
Content of file is read in my HTML instead of sending back towards the zip download.

PHP script :

```
<?php
require('config/config.php');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

$output = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $currentTime = time();
    if($currentTime < $_SESSION['expire'])
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['candidacy']))
        {
            $stmt = $cnx->prepare('SELECT * FROM candidacies WHERE id = :candidacy');
            $stmt->bindValue(':candidacy', $_POST['candidacy'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            var_dump($result);
            foreach($result as $key => $value)
            {
                $nameUser = $value['lastName']." ".$value['firstName'];
                $emailUser = $value['email'];
            }

            $pdf = new FPDF();

            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->Image('img/candidacy.jpg',10,6,25);

            $pdf->SetFont('Times','',13);

            $pdf->Cell(60);
            $pdf->Cell(80,10, utf8_decode('Candidacy'),1,1,'C');
            $pdf->ln();

            $pdf->Cell(60);
            $pdf->Cell(80,10, date("d/m/Y"),1,1,'C');
            $pdf->ln();

            $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Nom complet : ', 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($nameUser), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Email : ', 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(100,10, utf8_decode($emailUser), 0,1);

            $file = 'CCandidacy-'.$nameUser.'.pdf';

            $pdf->Output('F', $file);

            if(extension_loaded('zip'))
            {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();

                $zip_name = md5(random_bytes(64)).".zip";

                if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
                {
                    $output .= "Impossible to create zip !";
                }

                $zip->addFile($file);

                $zip->close();

                if(file_exists($zip_name))
                {
                    header('Content-type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name);
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));

                    readfile($zip_name);

                    unlink($zip_name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $output .= "Check extension !";
            }

            return $zip_name;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../login.php');
    exit(0);
}
```

JS script :

```
function zipExtract(candidacy)
{
    var content = {};
    content['candidacy'] = candidacy;

    $.post('zipCandidacy.php', content, function(data)
    {
        location.href = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: you can't download a file to disk directly using AJAX. The response will always be returned to your JavaScript, not to the user's device. You will have to either use a regular postback (you can fake a form submit with JS if needed), or save the zip to the server, and then have the AJAX return a URL to it, which you can then use JavaScript to navigate the browser to. Those are your options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution ! As you indicated it to me Oliver, AJAX was not the best way to define header like I wanted. Consequently, when the onclick event is executed, I redirect towards the php treatment page in order to proceed to the zip file download !

```
<?php
require('config/config.php');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

$output = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $currentTime = time();
    if($currentTime < $_SESSION['expire'])
    {
        if(!empty($_GET['candidacy']))
        {
            $stmt = $cnx->prepare('SELECT * FROM candidacies WHERE id = :candidacy');
            $stmt->bindValue(':candidacy', $_GET['candidacy'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach($result as $key => $value)
            {
                switch($value['zipcode'])
                {
                    case "North":
                        $zipcode = "Nord";
                        break;
                    case "South":
                        $zipcode = "Sud";
                        break;
                    case "East":
                        $zipcode = "Est";
                        break;
                    case "West":
                        $zipcode = "Ouest";
                        break;
                }

                switch($value['transportMeans'])
                {
                    case "onFoot":
                        $transportMeans = "À pied";
                        break;
                    case "vehicle":
                        $transportMeans = "Voiture";
                        break;
                    case "bike":
                        $transportMeans = "Moto";
                        break;
                    case "bus":
                        $transportMeans = "Bus";
                        break;
                    case "carpool":
                        $transportMeans = "Covoiturage";
                        break;
                    case "bicycle":
                        $transportMeans = "Vélo";
                        break;
                }

                switch($value['candidacyType'])
                {
                    case "mysteryCustomer":
                        $candidacyType = "Client Mystère";
                        break;
                    case "investigationUnit":
                        $candidacyType = "Chargé d'enquêtes";
                        break;
                    case "investigators":
                        $candidacyType = "Enquêteurs/Enquêtrices";
                        break;
                }

                $nameUser = $value['lastName']." ".$value['firstName'];
                $age = $value['age'];
                $employment = $value['employment'];
                $zipcode = $zipcode;
                $transportMeans = $transportMeans;
                $scheduleRange = $value['scheduleRange'];
                $emailUser = $value['email'];
                $phoneNumber = $value['phoneNumber'];
                $candidacyType = $candidacyType;
                $coveringLetter = $value['coveringLetter'];
                $curriculumVitae = $value['curriculumVitae'];
                $createdAt = $value['createdAt'];
            }

            $pdf = new FPDF();

            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->Image('img/candidacy.jpg',10,6,25);

            $pdf->SetFont('Times','',13);

            $pdf->Cell(60);
            $pdf->Cell(80,10, utf8_decode('Candidature'),1,1,'C');
            $pdf->ln();

            $pdf->Cell(60);
            $pdf->Cell(80,10, $createdAt,1,1,'C');
            $pdf->ln();

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Nom complet : ', 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($nameUser), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, utf8_decode('Âge : '),0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($age), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10,'Profession : ',0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($employment), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Secteur : ',0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($zipcode), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Moyen de transport :',0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($transportMeans), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Horaires : ',0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($scheduleRange), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Email : ', 0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(100,10, utf8_decode($emailUser), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, utf8_decode('N° de téléphone : '),0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($phoneNumber), 0,1);

            $pdf->Cell(50,10, 'Candidature : ',0,0);
            $pdf->Cell(65,10, utf8_decode($candidacyType), 0,1);

            $file = 'Candidature-'.$nameUser.'.pdf';

            $pdf->Output('F', $file);

            $files = array($file, "candidatures/".$coveringLetter, "candidatures/".$curriculumVitae);

            if(extension_loaded('zip'))
            {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();

                $zip_name = md5(random_bytes(64)).".zip";

                if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
                {
                    $error .= "Création impossible du zip !";
                }

                foreach($files as $content)
                {
                    $zip->addFile($content);
                }

                $zip->close();

                if(file_exists($zip_name))
                {
                    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name);
                    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));

                    readfile($zip_name);

                    unlink($zip_name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error .= "Vérifier l'extension !";
            }

            $query = $cnx->prepare('UPDATE candidacies SET lastExport = now() WHERE id = :candidacy');
            $query->bindValue(':candidacy', $_GET['candidacy'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
}
else
{
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../login.php');
    exit(0);
}


function zipExtract(candidacy)
{
    window.location.href = ("../zipCandidacy.php?candidacy="+candidacy);
}
```

Comment: perfect! the location.href part has to go in the frontend though even if it might be working as it is. Good luck, persist and enjoy :)

Comment: Ahah thx for ur support @Oliver! :) If you see another way to realize what I wish, do not hesitate to propose it!

Answer (score 0):

You can just redirect to the generated zip file using location.href once the ajax call is ready (would mean your zip file is ready too)

Return the url of the zip file from your PHP and then just use the below...

```
function zipExtract(candidacy)
{
    var content = {};
    content['candidacy'] = candidacy;

    $.post('zipCandidacy.php', content, function(data)
    {
       location.href=data;
    });
}
```

---

I don't think you need the below, but writing them just in case...

Keep in mind, you don't set headers in ajax. You set the headers in your php file using header() function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

mime type for zip (or just download if server cant satisfy your zip request)

`application/zip, application/octet-stream`

in PHP code..

```
// We'll be outputting a ZIP
header('Content-Type: application/zip, application/octet-stream');

// It will be called myzip.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myzip.zip"');

// your PHP code and FPDF stuff
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer @Oliver ! the problem is that my function in js relates onclick event. I have a list of candidacies and I propose a button to download in zip format, content of candidacy. On this onclick event, I retrieve id of clicked candidacy. That's why I'm using ajax

Comment: If I understood well, I add "return $zip_name" in my PHP and after, I modify my ajax that's right??

Comment: Hey, yes that's correct, make sure that you name your zip files with a unique code as if there's more than 1 person using your app/website you'll end up with files being overwritten.
Good luck! Ask more if you need help :)

Comment: Hum I edited my script, and tried it, the problem is that all the contents are from now in the url. The header for zip download doesn't display @Oliver

Comment: I tried another way, but still nothing :/                                                         function zipExtract(candidacy)
{
    var content = {};
    content['candidacy'] = candidacy;

    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"POST",
        url:"zipCandidacy.php",
        contentType: "application/zip",
        data: content,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('#zipContent').html(data);
        },
    });
}

Comment: update your code in your post and I'll check it for you